# How to filter MYSQL Result

Tags: mysql

I have database below is example

```
 ID  username
    1 FT0001
    2 FT0002
    3 FT0001
    4 FT0003
    5 FT0002
```

how to print only different values.

```
 ID  username
    1 FT0001
    2 FT0002
    4 FT0003
```

Comment: You mean to print random values ?

Comment: I can't believe how many wrong answers this has elicited. I despair for the future of SQL

Comment: Yeah because your answer is defiantly way better. I despair the future of SQL performance.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here but can't this be solved with a simple:  SELECT DISTINCT username FROM table_name;

Comment: @PetarZivkovic, I'm wondering the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

This should be easier:

```
SELECT DISTINCT username FROM table_name
```

Comment: Why isn't this the top answer? Does exactly what OP needs. Short, simple, to the point.

Answer (score 0):

You can group by the second column and use an aggregate function for the first:

```
SELECT MIN(ID), username 
FROM mytable
GROUP BY username
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select * from tbl_name group by username
```

Answer (score 0):

You could order by `field` and then limit the number of results you'd like.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    mytable
ORDER BY
    FIELD(`id`, '1','2','4')
LIMIT
    3
```

Ah - if you mean i'd like random values each time you could use `ORDER BY rand()`

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    mytable
ORDER BY
    rand()
```

Comment: Reason for downvoting @user3397800?

Answer (score 0):

Petar Zivkovic has answered it in the comments. `SELECT_DISTINCT` is what you're looking for, refer to this link:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT id, username
FROM table_name AS A
WHERE id=(SELECT MIN(id) FROM table_name AS B WHERE B.username=A.username)
```

Answer (score -1):

use groupby word.

```
select * from your_table group by second column;
```

Answer (score -3):

you can do this :
`select * from test where name = concat('FT000', 'id');`